# Git appears to use incorrect ancestor as base when merging

Tags: git, merge

I'm trying to merge our release branch into our feature branch, but git appears to be confused about what the common ancestor is.

I'm using SourceTree v3.1.2 and git v2.21.0.windows.1

**Before Feb 7**

Development branch was running parallel to Release branch, with changes being made to Development and hot fixes to Release.

**Feb 7**

Release was branched to Feature.

**May 9**

Development branch merged into Release branch.

**May 15 (Today)**

Trying to merge Release branch into Feature branch.
I end up with 78 conflicts.

- Some files were added to the Development branch before the merge - Can't see why these would be conflicts.
- Some files were existing, but not changed in the Feature branch - Can't see why these would be conflicts?
  Three way merge (in Beyond Compare 4) suggests a lot of code was removed in the Feature branch, when in fact it was added in the Development branch.
- Some files were changed in both branches, but have the same issue in the three way merge.

I can see what a mess the three way merge is when looking through the conflicts, so I'm unsure if the same problem has occurred to the non-conflicting files.  At a glance they look okay, but there's a lot of them so I can't be sure.

I ran the following git command that returned a seemingly random check-in on the Development branch from April 24.

git merge-base (latest Feature branch commit) (latest Release branch commit)

I would have thought I'd get the last commit before Development and Release diverged prior to Feb 7.

I've tried:

- Merging Release into Feature
- Merging Feature into Release
- Rebasing Feature onto Release (I don't think this is recommended, but I thought I'd try anyway) I seemed to loose a bunch of files doing this.
- Rebasing Release onto Feature
- Resetting to Feb 7 branch, re-branching, and then merging.
- Merging Development branch as at the time it was merged into Release.
- I've been trying to work out if I can force a common ancestor for the merge to work from, but I'm not sure I can do this from what I've read.

It's worth noting I did a trial merge of the Development branch (not the Release branch this time) into the Feature branch a few weeks ago and everything seemed to go quite well.  Since then I've upgraded SourceTree from version 1.7 to 3.1.2 which also required a git upgrade.

I'm not great with this git stuff, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I've been trying to work out if I can force a common ancestor for the merge to work from, but I'm not sure I can do this from what I've read.

No.  Git computes the merge base(s) for you.  They are based on the commit graph.

It's worth sitting down and drawing the graph (or having `git log --graph` do it for you).  Try using `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` (remember this as *get help from A DOG*), and maybe add `--simplify-by-decoration` to help drop a lot of the visual clutter.

#### Finding merge bases by eyeball

With simple graphs, it's easy to see, visually, which commit is the merge base of two other commits.  For instance, given a graph that can be displayed this way, with later commits towards the right:

```
          o--o--L   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         /
...--o--*
         \
          o--o--R   <-- branch2
```

... the merge base of commit `L` (your current checked-out commit, `HEAD`, at the tip of `branch1`) and commit `R` (the commit at the tip of `branch2`) is commit `*`.

Many graphs are horrible and tangled and not at all easy to parse visually like this.  Even some simpler ones are a little tricky at first.  A pretty common case occurs with repeated merges:

```
...--o--o--o--o--o--o--*--o--L   <-- branch1
         \     \        \
          o--o--A--o--o--B--o--R  <-- branch2
```

Once again, the merge base of `L` and `R` is commit `*`.  There are two existing merges, `A` and `B`.  Merge `A` is not relevant, because merge `B` creates the first commit reachable from both branch tips: we start at `L` and walk back two commits to `*`, and we start at `R`, walk back two commits to `B`, walk to its parent `*`, and have reached a shared commit.

#### Rebasing

> I've tried [rebasing]

Note that using `git rebase` *copies* commits, normally *discarding* merges.  Suppose you have the graph above, with merges into `branch2`, and you decide to `git rebase branch2 branch1`.  This will enumerate all the commits that are reachable from `branch2` but not from `branch1`, excluding merges.  While we can reach commit `*` from both `branch2` *and* `branch1`, we cannot reach *any* of the bottom-row commits from `branch1`.  So the commits to be copied are *all* the ones along the bottom row.  Let's give them all one-letter names so that we can talk about them:

```
...--o--o--o--o--o--o--*--o--L   <-- branch1
         \     \        \
          C--D--A--E--F--B--G--R  <-- branch2
```

(I've retained the one-letter names we already had for `A`, `B`, and `R` here).

The rebase operation—`git checkout branch2; git rebase branch1`—selects all the non-merge commits along the bottom row and copies them.  The copies go after commit `L`, at the tip of `branch1`, so that the result is:

```
                               C'-D'-E'-F'-G'-R'   <-- branch2
                              /
...--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--L   <-- branch1
         \     \        \
          C--D--A--E--F--B--G--R  <-- ???
```

While the *name* `branch2` has been moved at this point—it now points to `R'`, the copy of `R`—the original *commits* still exist.  They're just not *reachable* from the name `branch2` any more.

If there's another branch—say, `branch3`—that descends from some or all of these commits, we might draw that in:

```
                               C'-D'-E'-F'-G'-R'   <-- branch2
                              /
...--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--L   <-- branch1
         \     \        \
          C--D--A--E--F--B--G--R  <-- ???
                       \
                        H--I   <-- branch3
```

Since `R`, `G`, and `B` cannot be found easily, we can stop drawing them entirely:

```
                               C'-D'-E'-F'-G'-R'   <-- branch2
                              /
...--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--L   <-- branch1
         \     \
          C--D--A--E--F
                       \
                        H--I   <-- branch3
```

Commits `C-D-A-E-F` are still alive and well, though, reachable by starting at `branch3` (commit `I`) and working backwards.

If you now choose to merge `branch3` with `branch1` or `branch2`, the merge base is found by starting at both branch tips and working backwards as usual.  In this case, the merge base is the commit we reach by going up-and-left from commit `A` (the merge still reachable from the tip of `branch3`), since that commit is reachable from both branch tips and is the "closest to the end", as it were.

Because of this multiple-names-reach-the-old-commits thing, it's usually not wise to rebase branches that support other branches.  It's also tricky to rebase branches containing merges.  Modern (2.18+) Git has a `--rebase-merges` option that lets Git re-create the merges; older Git has `--preserve-merges` that attempts to do the same, but is more fragile than the modern method.  In all cases, though, it's important to know that when rebase has to copy a merge commit, it really just runs `git merge` again, so as to compute a *new* merge base, and redo the merge from scratch.

#### Additional notes

Note that the *date-and-time stamps* on commits are completely irrelevant here.  **Only the graph matters**.  The commits, with their node hash IDs and their parent edge hash IDs, form the commit graph.  The contents inside each commit are the history; the contents inside the merge base, and the two branch-tips, are what matters to `git merge`.

To have Git tell you what it's using for the merge base, do what you did, but add `--all` in case there are multiple merge bases:

```
git merge-base --all branch1 branch2
```

Git will do the merge-base finding: *start at last commit as pointed-to by the names, walk backwards along all paths, and find the best commit(s)*.  It will then print out the hash ID(s) of all the merge base(s).  The merge will then proceed by comparing (as with `git diff`) the (single) merge base against the two branch-tip commits.

If there *is* more than one merge base, the default `-s recursive` strategy will first run `git merge` on the merge bases themselves,<sup>1</sup> doing recursive merging until Git can come up with a single commit to be used as the "virtual merge base" of the merge process.  You can make Git just pick one of them at (apparent) random by using `-s resolve` instead.  That's not usually any improvement, but it's something to know about in complicated cases.

---

<sup>1</sup>Unless you're *really* unlucky / have gone quite crazy with your earlier graph-making, there will be a maximum of two merge bases.  If there are more, Git merges two, commits the result, merges that with the next, commits the result, and so on.

Comment: Thank you torek for your response.  Hopefully you cut and pasted most of that from something you already had available.  I tried to follow what you've said.  I think a lot of it makes sense. Finding the merge base by eyeball in your example is pretty straightforward, but with 3 months of commits by 8 people it proves quite difficult.  Most of what you said about rebasing matches my understanding.  I don't think I want to mess with that.  The --all option you suggested gave me that same result.  The seemingly random commit from April 24.

Comment: I will say I found something odd.  The graph provided by SourceTree (which I presume matches your get help from A DOG, but easier to follow) shows a line coming from the April 24 commit (on the Development branch by another user) and reconnecting with a commit on the Feature branch on May 1, with no other commits along the way. What is that?  I though it may have been something caused by my trial merge, but I did that on April 26.  Two days later.

Comment: The May 1 commit on the Feature branch was done by me.

Comment: I can't comment on what you see in SourceTree (which I don't have). Some graphical viewers have had bugs that draw incorrect graph-drawings, some work 100% of the time. (Beware the GitHub "network graph", which isn't related and is definitely not useful here.)

Comment: I just finished sorting out my issue by merging the commit before the May 1st one and then cherry picking the rest across.  I actually had to redo the May 1st one by hand as cherry picking wouldn't work.  Git thinks it's a merge commit.  I still can't see what it has to do with the April 24 commit on the development branch. It's just weird.  Thanks for your help anyway torek.  I learnt a few interesting things.

Comment: If Git thinks some commit is a merge commit, it *is* a merge commit: the definition of a "merge commit" is "any commit with two (or more) parents" and that's not something you can get wrong. Merges are really what define the graph shape / ancestry: without merges, everything is a simple linear chain going back in time to the very first commit.